# Spring returns FileSystemResource instead of ClassPathResource

Tags: spring

I'm attempting to retrieve a list of files in the classpath, but Spring is returning me a Resource[] of FileSystemResources instead of ClassPathResources. Here's what the code looks like:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource [] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:my/package/**/*.xml");
```

I've also tried this:

```
context.getResources("classpath*:my/package/**/*.xml");
```

The array returned is a bunch of absolute path file:// URLs, when what I really want is classpath: URLs. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I'm looking to ultimately build:

```
/my/package/one.xml
/my/package/two.xml
```

Instead I'm getting this:

```
file:/C:/eclipse/.../my/package/one.xml
```

Comment: Why would you care?  Why does your code depend on a `classpath:` resource, rather than just using the general `Resource` interface?

Comment: You are getting this: "file:/C:/eclipse/.../my/package/one.xml" But where do you get this URL? What is implementation type of returned resouces? Because you can have classpath resource with prefix file: in URL. Keyword classpath is just for spring.

Answer (score 0):

Both FileSystemResource and ClassPathResource return absolute resource path.  FileSystemResource looks for it in the file system `C:/eclipse/.../my/package/one.xml`. ClassPathResource looks for the resource on the classpath files inside `/WEB-INF/classes`. I don't understand why you need return `classpath:path`, however you still can get it by substring your absolute path.